# Unable to run localhost after completed docker run

Tags: docker

I have successfully run "docker run". How do I browse my web app?

[image]

I have tried localhost:8000 and localhost:81 but no success.

Updated with docker ps -a

[image]

My dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication4/WebApplication4.csproj", "WebApplication4/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication4/WebApplication4.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication4"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication4.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication4.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication4.dll"]
```

Comment: The `docker ps` did not show your container which run used `docker run`, the two containers' id is different in your picture. Use `docker ps -a` to confirm it please, it has been exit I think.

Comment: I run http://localhost:52010/ and it works now. But, I don't think this is in docker, right?

Comment: I run "docker inspect ea7bbc8f8134" to find the IP address and tried with http://172.17.0.1:52011/ but it doesn't work.

Comment: `-p` will mapping host port to container port, so use localhost:52010 is ok, the traffic will route to container. Don't use 172.17.0.1 which is meanless.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your setup, but I can't run the image embedded in the post; I just see the imgur URLs.  Do you have an actual Dockerfile for your image and the `docker run` command that you can add as text to the question?

Comment: @DavidMaze . Here is the dockerfile - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ewWwfx71doONmAUJ9CyDawOdPeSLb_1m

Answer (score 0):

You are able to access `localhost:52010` since the container that exposed the port `52010` is currently running, however the other containers have all exited. This is probably due to the fact that container `ea7` was run with the persistent `tail -f /dev/null` command, while the other containers were run with the non-persistent `bash` command.

The reason for this could be that the image you are trying to run does not have any command that persists and as soon as the container is created all running tasks in it are completed and the container exits.

Please make sure `webapplication4:dev` has a persistent command in it to keep the container from exiting.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I realize, that I could run localhost:52010 because I run from IIS express.

Comment: Please can you try accessing localhost:52011 and see if that works?

Comment: In most cases, the dll should persist and not terminate, keeping the container alive. If that is not the case, you can try `tail -f /dev/null` the way you ran the `ea7` container, the last container in the `docker ps -a` result screenshot.